# How to store data from text files into lists on integers

Tags: python

Hi hope everyone is okay.

I am trying to find the most simple method to take data from a text file and store it into diffrent
variables. Below is the format of a text file:

TEXT FILE:

min:1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9

avg:1,2,3,4

max:1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,44,55,32,12

I want to take each of these lines remove the part before the number starts (min,avg,max and the ':')
and store all the number data in seperate variables in their appropriate names.
NOTE: amount of numbers in each line may differ and shouldnt effect the code

desired in python:

min = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]

avg = [1,2,3,4]

max = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,44,55,32,12]

The code i have tried:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input:
    input = input.read()
    input = input.strip().split(',')
```

After this part i am unsure which method would be best to achieve what I am trying to do.
Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Do you have thoughts about what *input = input.read()* is going to do (notwithstanding that you've already shadowed the built-in *input()* function)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reasonable way to generate variables (by name) dynamically. Better to use a dictionary. Something like this:

```
my_dict = {}

with open('input.txt') as data:
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        try:
            key, vals = line.split(':')
            my_dict[key.rstrip()] = list(map(int, vals.split(',')))
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'min': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], 'avg': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'max': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 32, 12]}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, how could we change this so that we can get the list by specifiing 'min' so that it would print all the data that follows min, same for avg and max

Comment: @Slayer21 I refer you to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score -1):

Using [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for a string evaluation. Do that on trusted data to avoid injection attacks.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fd:
   data = fd.read()


# list of lines
lines = data.split('\n')

# python code format
code_format = '\n'.join("{} = [{}]".format(*line.partition(':')[::2]) for line in lines if line)

# execute the string as python code
exec(code_format)

print(avg)
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Notice that there is a further side effect in *this* code evaluation since some variable identifiers overload those of the built-in functions `min`, `max`. So, if after the execution of the code you try to call such build-in functions you will get `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`.

One way to re-approach the problem would be by *pickling* the objects and use `pickle.dumps` to save an object to a file and `pickle.loads` to retrieve the object, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps).

Comment: misunderstood the question, I will fix it

Comment: edited with a `exec`-approach

Answer (score -1):

This is how you store it in a python dictionary:

```
txtdict = {}
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.strip():
      name = line.split(':')[0]
      txtdict[name] = [int(i) for j in line.strip().split(':')[1:] for i in j.split(',')]
```

Output:

```
{'min': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9],
 'avg': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'max': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 32, 12]}
```

Comment: That's not really generating the desired output is it? It's also going to fail miserably if the input file contains empty lines as is apparently the case from the data shown in the question

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work correctly now based on the information he provided